# UITableViewCell will disappear

Tags: ios, uitableview

I made an UITableView and contained some custom UITableViewCells, in the fist cell (named cell0 for example) there are some UITextFields for input, when I scroll the tableView, cell0 will disappear from the top of screen, then How can I get the UITextField's text in cell0?

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` will return nil.

Comment: YOu need to give *tag* to each *textfield* and then in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` get its value.

Comment: @AhmedZ. I just scroll the tableView and not select the cell.

Comment: Please show some of your code for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) about `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, it returns "An object representing a cell of the table or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range."

A `UITableViewCell` is a view, according to [MVC Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). So I'd prefer maintaining a model object -- maybe it is as simple as a `NSString` instance -- to hold the text in the cell if I were you. You can observe `UITextField`'s change by adding an observer of `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` key to your controller.

```
- (void)textFieldDidChangeText:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Assume your controller has a NSString (copy) property named "text".
    self.text = [(UITextField *)[notification object] text]; // The notification's object property will return the UITextField instance who has posted the notification.
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Dequeue cell...
    // ...
    if (!cell)
    {
        // Init cell...
        // ...
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textFieldDidChangeText:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:yourTextField];
    }

    // Other code...
    // ...
    return cell;
}
```

Don't forget to remove the observer in your `-dealloc`.

Answer (score 18):

The only method I found is a tableview delegate

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [cell dealloc]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As `UITableViewCells` leave the viewable area of the `UITableView` it is actually *removed* from the tableview and placed back into the reuse queue. If it is the selected for reuse it will be returned by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.

There is no callback for when a cell is removed from the view. However, `prepareForReuse` is called on the cell just before it is returned by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.

What are you ultimately trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the text somewhere (e.g. an `NSArray`) the moment it gets changed.

Answer (score -3):

You can init textfield as instance variable.

look like:

.h

```
UITextField *textfiled;
```

.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    //init textfield
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //init cell...

    [cell addSubview:textfield];
    return cell;
}
```